# how to send value from android-project to share-project?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

how to send `verificationId` from `SendOtpCodeAsync()` to `SendCode_Button_Clicked()`

Share Project code

```
 IAuth auth; 
 auth = DependencyService.Get<IAuth>();
private async void SendCode_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       bool result = await auth.SendOtpCodeAsync(PhonenumberEntry.Text);
}
```

android project code

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AuthDriod))]
namespace TestApp_MiniApps.Droid
{
    public class AuthDriod : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks, IAuth
    {
        private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _phoneAuthTcs;

        public Task<bool> SendOtpCodeAsync(string phonenumber)
        {
            _phoneAuthTcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            Java.Lang.Long num = (Java.Lang.Long)60;
            PhoneAuthOptions options =
                PhoneAuthOptions.NewBuilder(FirebaseAuth.Instance)
                .SetPhoneNumber(phonenumber)       // Phone number to verify
                .SetTimeout(num, TimeUnit.Seconds) // Timeout and unit
                .SetActivity(Platform.CurrentActivity)                 // Activity (for callback binding)
                .SetCallbacks(this)          // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
                .Build();
            PhoneAuthProvider.VerifyPhoneNumber(options);

            return _phoneAuthTcs.Task;
        }

        public override void OnVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential)
        {      
        }

        public override void OnVerificationFailed(FirebaseException exception)
        {
            _phoneAuthTcs?.TrySetResult(false);
        }

        public override void OnCodeSent(string verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken)
        {
            base.OnCodeSent(verificationId, forceResendingToken);
            _phoneAuthTcs?.TrySetResult(true);

        }
    }//end of class
}
```

share project interface

```
namespace TestApp_MiniApps.Views.Xamarin.FireBase
{
    public interface IAuth
    {
        Task<bool> SendOtpCodeAsync(string phonenumber);
    }//end of class
}
```

Comment: the stack trace should show you the line number causing the exception

Comment: thanks for getting back. yeah error is bc i am passing string from `share-project` to `android-project`. I tried converting to `String` and `ToString` as well

Comment: I doubt that is the cause.  The only obvious cast you are doing is to Java.Lang.Long.  If you would look at the stack trace as I suggested it would confirm this

Comment: And the problem is what?  What happens when you try it?  Does this not compile?  Or you get an exception when you run? Which line of code does it fail on?

Comment: question i how to send value. i looked on google but had hard time finding some this similar. do you any idea how can i send it or maybe i can look though some links that you might have?

Comment: Have you tried to change the return value of the callback from `bool` to the type you want ?

Comment: You may try `MessagingCenter`

Answer (score 1):

To summarise what Leo had put in the comments you can check what is returned from your method call.

Change from `bool` to your own class. For the purpose of this answer I will call it `OtpResult`.

```cs
// The new class definition:
public class OtpResult
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    // Define whatever you like here
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
}


public interface IAuth
{
    Task<OtpResult> SendOtpCodeAsync(string phonenumber);
}
```

Comment: i was looking at xamarin documents.. they have `secure storage` `clipboard` and `performance`. i think it would be simiple if i use those to pass values betwween pages. is this a bad idea? let me know

Comment: @ikhlasahmed that is likely a topic for another question on here but I would not recommend using those options. Try something like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/navigation-passingdata/